# How to encode Bitmaps into a video using MediaCodec?

Tags: android, bitmap, h.264, android-4.2-jelly-bean, video-encoding

I would like to encode a set of Bitmaps that I have into an h264. Is this possible via MediaEncoder? I have written some code in order to do it, but the output cannot be played in any media player I have tried. Here's some of the code that I primarily borrowed from other sources that I found on Stackoverflow.

```
mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
mMediaCodec.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mMediaCodec.start();
mInputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream); // image is the bitmap
byte[] input = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mInputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
    inputBuffer.clear();
    inputBuffer.put(input);
    mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
}
```

What should I adjust?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have modified the code provided by abalta to accept bitmaps in realtime (ie you don't already need to have the bitmaps saved to disc). It also has a performance improvement since you don't need to write then read the bitmaps from disc. I also increased the TIMEOUT_USEC from the original example which fixed some timeout related errorsng I was having.

Hopefully this helps someone. I spent a long time trying to do this without having to pack a large third party library into my app (ex ffmpeg), so I really appreciate abalta's answer.

I am using rxjava, so you will need this in your app's build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
```

If you are trying to write to external storage you will need the external storage permission defined in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and either manually toggle the permission on in the system Settings app for your app, or add permission request handling for it to your activity.

And here is the class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaCodecList;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class BitmapToVideoEncoder {
    private static final String TAG = BitmapToVideoEncoder.class.getSimpleName();

    private IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback mCallback;
    private File mOutputFile;
    private Queue<Bitmap> mEncodeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private MediaMuxer mediaMuxer;

    private Object mFrameSync = new Object();
    private CountDownLatch mNewFrameLatch;

    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc"; // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static int mWidth;
    private static int mHeight;
    private static final int BIT_RATE = 16000000;
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30; // Frames per second

    private static final int I_FRAME_INTERVAL = 1;

    private int mGenerateIndex = 0;
    private int mTrackIndex;
    private boolean mNoMoreFrames = false;
    private boolean mAbort = false;

    public interface IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback {
        void onEncodingComplete(File outputFile);
    }

    public BitmapToVideoEncoder(IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public boolean isEncodingStarted() {
        return (mediaCodec != null) && (mediaMuxer != null) && !mNoMoreFrames && !mAbort;
    }

    public int getActiveBitmaps() {
        return mEncodeQueue.size();
    }

    public void startEncoding(int width, int height, File outputFile) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mOutputFile = outputFile;

        String outputFileString;
        try {
            outputFileString = outputFile.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get path for " + outputFile);
            return;
        }

        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
        if (codecInfo == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find an appropriate codec for " + MIME_TYPE);
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "found codec: " + codecInfo.getName());
        int colorFormat;
        try {
            colorFormat = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, MIME_TYPE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
        }

        try {
            mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create MediaCodec " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, I_FRAME_INTERVAL);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();
        try {
            mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFileString, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"MediaMuxer creation failed. " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initialization complete. Starting encoder...");

        Completable.fromAction(() -> encode())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
    }

    public void stopEncoding() {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to stop encoding since it never started");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping encoding");

        mNoMoreFrames = true;

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    public void abortEncoding() {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to abort encoding since it never started");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Aborting encoding");

        mNoMoreFrames = true;
        mAbort = true;
        mEncodeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(); // Drop all frames

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    public void queueFrame(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to queue frame. Encoding not started");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Queueing frame");
        mEncodeQueue.add(bitmap);

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    private void encode() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Encoder started");

        while(true) {
            if (mNoMoreFrames && (mEncodeQueue.size() ==  0)) break;

            Bitmap bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll();
            if (bitmap ==  null) {
                synchronized (mFrameSync) {
                    mNewFrameLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                }

                try {
                    mNewFrameLatch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll();
            }

            if (bitmap == null) continue;

            byte[] byteConvertFrame = getNV21(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap);

            long TIMEOUT_USEC = 500000;
            int inputBufIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
            long ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(mGenerateIndex, FRAME_RATE);
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                inputBuffer.clear();
                inputBuffer.put(byteConvertFrame);
                mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, byteConvertFrame.length, ptsUsec, 0);
                mGenerateIndex++;
            }
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int encoderStatus = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet
                Log.e(TAG, "No output from encoder available");
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                MediaFormat newFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                mTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                mediaMuxer.start();
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
            } else if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                ByteBuffer encodedData = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                if (encodedData == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                } else {
                    encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);
                    mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                }
            }
        }

        release();

        if (mAbort) {
            mOutputFile.delete();
        } else {
            mCallback.onEncodingComplete(mOutputFile);
        }
    }

    private void release() {
        if (mediaCodec != null) {
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            mediaCodec = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"RELEASE CODEC");
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            mediaMuxer = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"RELEASE MUXER");
        }
    }

    private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                    return codecInfo;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int selectColorFormat(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo,
                                         String mimeType) {
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo
                .getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
        for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length; i++) {
            int colorFormat = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
            if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat)) {
                return colorFormat;
            }
        }
        return 0; // not reached
    }

    private static boolean isRecognizedFormat(int colorFormat) {
        switch (colorFormat) {
            // these are the formats we know how to handle for
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {

        int[] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

        scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        byte[] yuv = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2];
        encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        scaled.recycle();

        return yuv;
    }

    private void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = frameSize;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;


                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;


                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));

                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private long computePresentationTime(long frameIndex, int framerate) {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / framerate;
    }
}
```

Usage is something like:

```
BitmapToVideoEncoder bitmapToVideoEncoder = new BitmapToVideoEncoder(new IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onEncodingComplete(File outputFile) {
        Toast.makeText(this,  "Encoding complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

bitmapToVideoEncoder.startEncoding(getWidth(), getHeight(), new File("some_path"));
bitmapToVideoEncoder.queueFrame(bitmap1);
bitmapToVideoEncoder.queueFrame(bitmap2);
bitmapToVideoEncoder.queueFrame(bitmap3);
bitmapToVideoEncoder.queueFrame(bitmap4);
bitmapToVideoEncoder.queueFrame(bitmap5);
bitmapToVideoEncoder.stopEncoding();
```

And if your recording is interrupted (ex Activity is pausing) you can abort and it will delete the file (since it would be corrupt anyway). Alternatively just call stopEncoding and it will properly close the file so it is not corrupt:

```
bitmapToVideoEncoder.abortEncoding();
```

There is also a getActiveBitmaps() function to see how big the queue is (if the queue gets to big you can run out of memory). Also here is some code to efficiently create a bitmap from a view so you can queue it up (my app takes periodic screenshots and encodes them into a video):

```
View view = some_view;
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image.
final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("PixelCopier");
handlerThread.start();

PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, (copyResult) -> {
    bitmapToVideoEncoder.queueFrame(bitmap);
}, new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()));
```

Comment: I am getting the following error in the stopEncoding method - any tips? 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.getCount()' on a null object reference`

Comment: If mNewFrameLatch is null then I think the encoder didn't successfully start. I changed some of the logging to help you debug. If everything is working you should see "Initialization complete. Starting encoder..." and "Encoder started" in logcat. If you don't see these messages, there is probably an error message which can give you more details on the problem. Make sure the outputFile you provide to startEncoding is writable.

Comment: If you are trying to write to external storage you will need the external storage permission defined in your manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and either manually toggle the permission on in the system Settings app for your app, or add permission request handling for it to your activity. The former is a good shortcut to check if this is the problem. You can also try writing to Context.getDataDir() instead which does not need any special storage permission, but only your app will be able to read the output file.

Comment: Did a bit of debugging and figured something out, sorta. Everything works as expected if I use postDelayed to delay the call to `bitmapToVideoEncoder.stopEncoding()` by 2000 ms. Not a permanent solution but it is working, I am guessing there is still a race condition somewhere then maybe?

Comment: The purpose of the latch is to allow you to call stopEncoding() even though there still may be bitmaps in the queue being processed. It let's it first finish processing the bitmaps, then finalizes the video. Are you by chance processing a very small number of frames? Or maybe you already have a bunch of bitmaps in memory so you are calling stopEncoding very quickly? If so it is possible stopEncoding() is being called before it has a chance to initialize the latch.

Comment: Correction: The latch is used to make the encoder thread block and wait in case you are not feeding in bitmaps as fast as it can process them (which was the case when I used this code). If you can feed in the bitmaps quick enough, it never needs to initialize the latch and leads to the crash. I modified the code to do null checks for the latch. I also removed a line from stopEncoding() where it was flushing the queue; this was something copied over from abortEncoding() which I should not have.

Comment: Aha! That seems to have fixed it, Thank you! One thing I noticed in playing around is that the buffer seems to consistently have 2 frames remaining after the encode while loop breaks so I added a call to `writeSampleData` to finish them out before breaking. It won't matter for most use cases but I am using a low fps with only a few frames. I think it happens because you can add frames to the inputbuffer but they won't always get written right after. The check to break out of the encode while loop only checks if all frames have gone to the buffer not if they have been written to the video.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked for you. Good catch on the final frames, I am encoding much longer videos so didn't notice.

Comment: Thank you for the great class. I'm getting this error after a few seconds of encoding: io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Can't call getPixels() on a recycled bitmap
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.EmptyCompletableObserver.onError(EmptyCom

Comment: It looks like one or more of the bitmaps you are passing in to queueFrame() are being recycled before the encoder is able to process them. Check your calling code that is using the BitmapToVideoEncoder class and make sure you aren't doing anything with the bitmap after passing it to queueFrame().

Comment: For some reason it encodes the bitmaps to black/white/gray colors instead of full colors. The colorFormat is 19. see this sample video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaJsV0XMeCQ  
What do you think might caused this to happen?

Comment: Try displaying one of the bitmaps you are trying to encode in an ImageView, or save to disk and view in your photos app. Is it already grey before even passing it to the encoder? Are you allocating the bitmap with Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 like the sample code above?
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: How I merge a mp3/wav audio file to generate video ?

Comment: I have a couple users reporting the black and white video issue that @Adibarba saw. I can confirm that I am allocating the bitmaps with ARGB_8888 and saving them out I see that they are full color when passed to the encoder. I can't seem to pin down the issue but am investigating. I found that I can reproduce it in Android Studio emulator with nexus 5 api 25.

Comment: @Adibarda I figured out the issue - `colorformat` needs to be set to `MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` explicitly. Right now it is set to that only if `selectColorFormat` fails (see the catch block). We are manually creating a semiplanar yuv so we need to set it to that rather than just picking a format the phone supports as `selectColorFormat` does.

Comment: I used the code, but i was getting this exception 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't call getPixels() on a recycled bitmap.                            

I had to comment out // scaled.recycle(); on line 304

Comment: How can I repeate a frame for 1 seconds instead queue 30 copies of the same bitmap?

Answer (score 21):

The output of `MediaCodec` is a raw H.264 elementary stream.  I've found that the Totem media player for Linux is able to play them.

What you really want to do is convert the output to a .mp4 file.  (**Update:**) Android 4.3 (API 18) introduced the [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class, which provides a way to convert the raw data (plus an optional audio stream) to a .mp4 file.

The layout of data in the `ByteBuffer` is, as of Android 4.3, device-dependent.  (In fact, not all devices support `COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar` -- some prefer a semi-planar variant.)  I can't tell you the exact layout without knowing your device, but I can tell you that it wants uncompressed data, so passing in compressed PNG data is not going to work.

(**Update:**) Android 4.3 also allows Surface input to `MediaCodec` encoders, so anything you can render with OpenGL ES can be recorded.  For an example, see the EncodeAndMuxTest sample [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

Comment: Would it be possible for me to move the output to a pc and encode it to mp4 there? Is there any way to universally determine the correct format for the input for all compatible Android devices?

Comment: I believe you can do the conversion off-device, but I don't have a specific program to recommend.  As of Android 4.2, you can query the codec for the formats that it supports, but not all devices treat the format the same way (e.g. some have alignment restrictions on the start of the chroma data).

Comment: Android 4.3 added Surface input and `MediaMuxer` conversion to .mp4.  Answer updated.

Comment: @BVB What does this problem end up with? I am using MediaMuxer but the video output is gibberish. I did not do the PNG-YUV420 conversion as user2399321 suggested though. Do we need that? If a separate question is needed, I am happy to do so. Thanks!

Comment: You need to query the codec for the list of supported formats, and use one of those.  As of Android 4.3, all devices must support YUV420 planar or semi-planar.  I've never seen one support RGB input from a `ByteBuffer`.  You can see how this is done in the buffer-to-buffer or buffer-to-surface tests in http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest .

Comment: Yeah, you need it to be in the YUV420 format. I actually ended up going with a different route and used FFmpeg for my needs.

Comment: Anyone interested in a muxer solution for below 4.3 can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23000620/727768

Comment: @xdevelopery Is there a good way to have variable framerate and to tell each frame its time? For example, how can I tell the first frame to be at 0 ms, the second to be at 347 ms, the third to be at 512 ms, etc?

Answer (score 11):

I used following steps to convert my bitmaps to video file.

**Step 1: Preparing**

I have prepared encoder like this. I use MediaMuxer to create a mp4 file.

```
    private void prepareEncoder() {
    try {
        mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

        mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
        mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, calcBitRate());
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
        }else{
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible);
        }
        //2130708361, 2135033992, 21
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

        final MediaFormat audioFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MIME_TYPE_AUDIO, SAMPLE_RATE, 1);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_MASK, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
        audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);

        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();

        mediaCodecForAudio = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE_AUDIO);
        mediaCodecForAudio.configure(audioFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodecForAudio.start();

        try {
            String outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "test.mp4").toString();
            mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MediaMuxer creation failed", ioe);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Buffering**

I have created runnable for buffering.

```
private void bufferEncoder() {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                prepareEncoder();
                try {
                    while (mRunning) {
                        encode();
                    }
                    encode();
                } finally {
                    release();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
```

**Step 3: Encoding**

This is the most important part that you have missed. In this part, I have prepared input buffer before output. When input buffers queued, output buffers are ready to encoding.

```
public void encode() {
            while (true) {
                if (!mRunning) {
                    break;
                }
                int inputBufIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                long ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(generateIndex);
                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                    Bitmap image = loadBitmapFromView(captureImageView);
                    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);
                    byte[] input = getNV21(WIDTH, HEIGHT, image);
                    final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                    inputBuffer.clear();
                    inputBuffer.put(input);
                    mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, input.length, ptsUsec, 0);
                    generateIndex++;
                }
                int encoderStatus = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // no output available yet
                    Log.d("CODEC", "no output from encoder available");
                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    // not expected for an encoder
                    MediaFormat newFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                    mTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                    mediaMuxer.start();
                } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                    Log.i("CODEC", "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
                } else if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        Log.i("CODEC", "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                    } else {
                        encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                        encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);
                        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                        mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step 4: Releasing**

Finally, if we finished encoding then release the muxer and encoder.

```
private void release() {
        if (mediaCodec != null) {
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            mediaCodec = null;
            Log.i("CODEC", "RELEASE CODEC");
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            mediaMuxer = null;
            Log.i("CODEC", "RELEASE MUXER");
        }
    }
```

I hope this will helps to you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: I was a little confused by some of the methods that aren't included in the answer, such as `computePresentationTime()`. In case it helps anyone, it looks like the code in this answer was partially based on this open-source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java

Comment: @RafaelLima, I know. I want to explain concept of using MediaMuxer.

Comment: @abalta : I don't know about MediaCodec.
Is there any demo code available on GitHub?

Comment: Hi @ravi152, there are some demos on Github. Try these links; https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample https://github.com/cedricfung/MediaCodecDemo https://github.com/PhilLab/Android-MediaCodec-Examples/blob/master/EncodeDecodeTest.java

Comment: How do you set the frame duration of each frame (instead of all the same) ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Encoders output is "raw" h264, so you can set filename extension to "h264" and play it with mplayer, ie `mplayer ./your_output.h264`
2. One more thing: you says to encoder that frame will be in COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar color format but it looks like you give him PNG content, so output file will probably contain color mess. I think you should convert PNG to yuv420 (with this, for example, https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/) before feeding it to encoder.

Comment: Are other formats supported? What would I use if I wanted to put in raw bitmap bytes in there?

Comment: You can find supported formats in developers documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html . But before configuring encoder to use some color format you need to iterate all codecs and check their capabilities (using this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecList.html).

Comment: If encoder does support COLOR_Format32bitARGB8888 or COLOR_Format32bitBGRA8888 you can use PNG content (I've never met such devices though). Otherwise the image should be converted from PNG to some sort of yuv. If conversion is not time critical process you can write own java code but you should deal with yuv content (here is starting point - http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php).