# MediaRecorder stop failed: -1007

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I am using a `SurfaceView` which shows the stream of the drone on my smartphone and what I want is to record the stream of the drone, but it's not that easy. So I think I could use `MediaRecorder` for this. For this problem I have read many posts, but they didn't help me out.

In the `OnCreate` I am creating the `SurfaceView`:

```
        mPreview = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surfaceView1);
        holder = mPreview.Holder;
        holder.AddCallback(this);
        holder.SetFormat(Format.Rgba8888);
```

In the `SurfaceCreated` override I added the `SetPreviewDisplay`:

```
        mRecorder = new Android.Media.MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.SetPreviewDisplay(mPreview.Holder.Surface);
```

So, when I click on the record button I start the following method in a new thread, otherwise the `SurfaceView` will be stuck:

```
    private void StartRecord()
    {
        var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.mp4");

        file = new File(path);

        mRecorder.SetVideoSource(Android.Media.VideoSource.Surface);
        mRecorder.SetOutputFormat(Android.Media.OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        mRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(Android.Media.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mRecorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mRecorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
        mRecorder.SetOutputFile(file.AbsolutePath);
        mRecorder.SetVideoSize(mPreview.Width, mPreview.Height);

        mRecorder.Prepare();
        mRecorder.Start();
    }
```

There are no errors until the `mRecorder.Stop()` will be called:

```
    private void StopRecord()
    {
        if(mRecorder != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mRecorder.Stop();
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.RuntimeException e)
            {
                // Here he always comes
                file.Delete();
                System.Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                mRecorder.Release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I check into the `mRecorder` variable, it's saying at the surface object: `failed to get surface`. That's strange because when I check the `mRecorder` variable after the `mRecorder` started, it just has a surface object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, a `Surface` is the producer endpoint of a producer-consumer pair. For a SurfaceView, you write to the Surface, and they are displayed by the system graphics compositor (SurfaceFlinger). Saying "record a SurfaceView" doesn't make any sense, unless you're talking about a virtual display. (I'm not familiar with Xamarin, so I can't offer anything more specific.)

Comment: @fadden, that's right, I meant record the stream of the drone which is viewable on my SurfaceView on my smartphone. It's already creating a file on my smartphone named `test.mp4`, but it will be deleted, because I've got a `RuntimeException`. I just don't know why `mRecorder.Stop()` is crashing...

Comment: @fadden, I see you have also a lot of experience with encoding and decoding of videos. What I am trying right now is to convert the bitmaps to a .mp4 file. I need the MediaCodec which converts it firstly to a raw .h264 file.  After that I need to use the MediaMuxer which provides a way to convert it to a mp4 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096726/how-to-encode-bitmaps-into-a-video-using-mediacodec). My question is: where can I set the output path from the .h264 file? Because I need to put it somewhere on the phone, right?

Comment: The buffers of encoded video from MediaCodec are fed into MediaMuxer. You provide a filename to MediaMuxer. There's no H.264 file. You can find various examples on bigflake (http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) and in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika). Exceptions and error codes from MediaCodec tend to be less than useful, but sometimes the error messages from logcat are informative.