# MP4 Muxed on Android Skips Final Frame but only in Some Applications

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, mp4

I am using the media muxer on Android to create an mp4. Basically I am feeding bitmaps to the muxer and encoding each bitmap as 1 second of video. Everything is working fine except that the last frame of video (the last bitmap) flashes at the very end of the video but doesn't also hold for 1 full second. This occurs when sharing to instagram, hangouts etc but if I pull the mp4 up on my mac it plays the full final second. Does anyone know what may be causing this? I am using this implementation:

[How to encode Bitmaps into a video using MediaCodec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096726/how-to-encode-bitmaps-into-a-video-using-mediacodec)