# Display android.graphics.Bitmap constantly in TextureView

Tags: android, video, bitmap, textureview, grafika

I have written a Fragment class, which is dedicated to display a constant stream of android.graphics.Bitmap. The stream of Bitmap objects is delivered by JavaCV.

Do I have to use the Canvas.drawBitmap method to display the Bitmaps in order to get a video?

The class looks like this

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass for showing th Video stream.
 */
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_video)
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, VideoListener {
    public static final String TAG = "de.mw.talk2drone.ui.video.VideoFragment";
    @ViewById
    TextureView textureView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(@NonNull final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(@NonNull final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(@NonNull final SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(@NonNull final SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameReceived(TelloVideoFrame frame) {
        Log.d(TAG, "received a frame in Fragment: " +frame);
    }
}
```

Do you have some samples or links of how to smoothly display a Bitmap stream in a TextureView? I have seen multiple references to Grafika, which may give a clue of what has to been done.

Comment: Here is a related discussion that might help - [(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51278232/7604766](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51278232/7604766)

Comment: @KalpeshChandora No, this does not relate to my question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should render the bitmap frame by frame by yourself in onFrameReceived method, simply you can use a timer the update frame to glview,
what's more , you need a buffer queue to hold input frames and render them in order;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35296702)